# How can I include additional tests if a test passes?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, system-testing

I'm using `nose` to run some system tests, one of which is to test whether a (config) file exists. If this file exists, I'd like to run some additional tests on it. If not, I'd like to skip a bunch of tests.

What's the best approach to take to make `nose` include the additional tests if the main test passes?

Comment: check the return value of the assert statements and set up a conditional would be the easy way

Comment: you could create a decorator, where if config file does not exist invoke unittest .skip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use skipTest from the setUp method in your specific TestCase, like:

```
import os
from unittest import TestCase

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        if not os.path.exists('configfile'):
            return self.skipTest('config file not found')

    def test01(self):
        # Do something with the file
        with open('configfile') as fd:
            self.assertEqual(fd.readlines().__len__(), 0)
```

test test01 would not run if config file does not exist.

Comment: I believe `SkipTest` is an exception that should be raised, not returned.